Ошибка при добавлении в запрос SQL фильтра по периоду
У меня есть такой запрос в MySQL для полкчения информации по чекам
SELECT SUM(`order`.total) as totalWithoutDiscount,
       SUM(IF(`order`.total_with_sale != 0, `order`.total_with_sale, `order`.total)) as totalWithDiscount,
       (SUM(`order`.total) - SUM(IF(`order`.total_with_sale != 0, `order`.total_with_sale, `order`.total))) as discount,
       `check`.payment_type as paymentType,
       `check`.order_type as orderType,
       `check`.id as checkId
FROM `check`,
     `order`,
     `posinfo`
WHERE `check`.id = :id
  AND `order`.canseled = false
  AND `check`.id = `order`.order_check_id
  AND `check`.status = 7
  AND `check`.id_pos in (`posinfo`.id);

Мне надо доработать этот запрос, чтобы получать статистику по всем чекам за период, заданный двумя датами from и to. Но когда я добавляю условия на даты, я получаю ошибку:
SELECT SUM(`order`.total) as totalWithoutDiscount,
       SUM(IF(`order`.total_with_sale != 0, `order`.total_with_sale, `order`.total)) as totalWithDiscount,
       (SUM(`order`.total) - SUM(IF(`order`.total_with_sale != 0, `order`.total_with_sale, `order`.total))) as discount,
       `check`.payment_type as paymentType,
       `check`.order_type as orderType,
       `check`.id as checkId
FROM `check`,
     `order`,
     `posinfo`
WHERE `check`.time >= '2024-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND `check`.time < '2024-01-31 23:59:59'
  AND `order`.canseled = false
  AND `check`.id = `order`.order_check_id
  AND `check`.status = 7
  AND `check`.id_pos in (`posinfo`.id);

Ошибка такая:

In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #4 of SELECT list
contains nonaggregated column 'testdb.check.payment_type'; this is
incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Как исправить эту ошибку и доработать запрос, чтобы выводилась статистика за период? Почему эта ошибка произошла?

Ну так исходный запрос кривой. Крайне странно, что он не приводит к той же самой ошибке. Либо он выполняется на другом сервере, либо имеются предварительные команды изменения @@sql_mode для текущей сессии. Как исправить эту ошибку Переписать запрос, чтобы он был корректным. Не использовать неполную группировку. либо убрать неагрегированные поля аргументами в соотв. функции. В общем, читать про ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
